# Difference bundle, bundle install, bundle update

Tags: bundle

What are differences amongst `bundle`, `bundle install`, `bundle update`?

Could you tell me when I should use

```
bundle
bundle install
bundle update
```

Comment: Easy - just read the documentation (isn't "install" vs "update" sort of self-explanatory anyway?): http://gembundler.com/#use-bundler

Answer (score 5):

Bundle install will install gems according to Gemfile spec and put them in gemenv. Bundle update updates all gems to the latest version.

Comment: And "bundle" seems to be a simple alias for "bundle install".